# Can I programmatically get installed application category?

Tags: android

From last few days I research on this topic and i found like on OS Android 5 and above we can get application category like I only want to know Is it a game or not (`ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME`) but i couldn't found all Game Categoriesfrom this method so after that i implemented PlayStore request https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=APPLICATIONID but it take a time and also need internet.

I saw some application which are fast to fetch game without Internet I don't know how 
Please help me to resolve it 
Thanking You

Comment: What apps "fetch game without Internet"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)  (`like android:isGame=["true" | "false"]`)

Android manifest permission for Application tag

Comment: (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_IS_GAME)  from this tag Right ?? but candy crush saga in not coming in this category i dont know how

Comment: @BhanuSharma candy crush may be not set this in manifest that's way it is not coming in this category

Comment: @BhanuSharma Add Tag in your manifest and when you upload app on play store you have to select your app category than playstore automatically manage this thing

Comment: no no i want to category list of game from installed apps so that i have to show candy crush and many these type of game

Comment: @BhanuSharma No game fatch off line  when you connect with internet game download resource in background. can't update game without any internet if you have any game that do like this please provide link

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trendmicro.dr.booster&hl=en  close your internet and it will fatch off all games

Comment: @BhanuSharma I have Reverse engineered that application and the application having wide range of package name in it's database and compare it with installed app package name and if it found package name from its data base than display app in list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113483/discussion-between-jack-and-bhanu-sharma).

Comment: @BhanuSharma Did you got your ans?

Comment: @BhanuSharma If you want ans, reverse engineer that app and go to assets you will get database with packagename

Comment: @BhanuSharma if answer is right please accept it so other can also get know about this thing

Comment: J.D. Could you share the answer, how did you get categories of apps without internet connection?

Comment: @BhanuSharma Did you get the answer?

Comment: @Makvin Yes, I did but with PlayStore request approach. All other apps maintain their database so that they compare locally

Answer (score 0):

Application categories correspond to a classification in Android Market, but not something you can check on the application itself. What you can do is to query the Android Market for information of a specific application.

Comment: i already do it from play store queary but what about if internet is off or not working.Many app do it without internet